# Creating a binary-only Erlang release

Tags: erlang, rebar

I have created a release of my program with rebar.  Navigating around in the output directory I see my Erlang source files.  Is there any way to create binary only releases of Erlang programs, so that they can be distributed (as closed source) to customers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in rebar.config file. {include_src, false} in prod section

```
{profiles, [
        {dev1, [{relx, [{dev_mode, false},
                         {include_erts, false},
                         {sys_config, "./config/dev1/sys.config"},
                         {vm_args, "./config/dev1/vm.args"}]}
                ]
        },
        {prod, [{relx, [{dev_mode, false},
                        {include_erts, true},
                        {include_src, false},
                        {sys_config, "./config/prod/sys.config"},
                        {vm_args, "./config/prod/vm.args"}]}]
```